# Setting checkbox to disabled or clickable to false disables animation

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I have 4 check boxes which are checked one by one while entering pin code. I don't want the user check or uncheck them manually, so I tried to use `setEnabled(false)` and/or `setClickable(false)`. It works fine, but disables my check/uncheck animation too.
Is there any other way to do this, or maybe workaround (maybe recognizing which check box was unchecked, and removing this value from table, and also not letting him to check manually [there is no any value then])

Comment: you can create a class that can be observed if any changes occurred,or you can use LiveData(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: In my opinion, if disabling the Checkbox stops the animation, it would advice you to enable the checkbox `onAnimationStart` and disable the Checkbox again `onAnimationEnd`. You can access these methods via `anim.setAnimationListener` listener